# Passing data in an iOS 10 Segue between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I created a UIBarButtonItem in my View Controller. In my Storyboard, I control clicked the UIBarButtonItem and dragged it to a new view controller which pushes the new View Controller into the navigation stack when I click the UIBarButtonItem.

My problem is when I click on the button, I want to pass the view controller data before it's presented. I'm not entirely sure if I should be abandoning Storyboards to make this happen and handle everything in code or if there is a way to override some method(s) to facilitate this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare). You'd override this in your calling view controller and access the destination view controller here.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MySegue",
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        destinationViewController.object = selectedObject
    }
}
```